# Взаимодействие с формой через другой класс

Tags: c++, mvc, form

Мне нужно в конце игры отобразить кнопку перезагрузки игры, которая в центре на картинке, ну и в дальнейшем возможно реализовать и другое взаимодействие с формой. Правильно ли будет передавать Контроллеру класс формы TGameForm? Просто иначе я не знаю как сделать на ней какие-то действия. В Java написал бы кучу интерфейсов и переопределил бы в Контроллере, но здесь я так не могу сделать.

Какое решение данной проблемы вы можете предложить?

```
class TMainForm : public TForm, public IListener
```

При попытке множественного наследования с классом TForm, выдается ошибка:

> IListener is not abstract public single inheritance class hierarchy
>   with no data

Код абстрактного класса:

```
class IListener {
public:
    virtual ~IListener() {
    }
    virtual void Update()=0;
};
```

[image: Интерфейс: кнопка перезагрузки]

Comment: А почему Вы здесь не можете сделать так, как привыкли в Java? В ++ нет слова `interface`, но чисто абстрактный класс - то же самое.

Comment: Нашел единственный адекватный ответ VCL dont allow multiple inheritance. Что можно ещё попробовать сделать в этом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело оказалось в том, что в моём абстрактном классе IListener был деструктор, а для множественного наследования с классами VCL необходимо, чтобы абстрактный класс содержал только виртуальные функции и ничего более.

```
class IListener {
public:
    virtual void UpdateData()=0;
};
```

P.S. Конкретно виртуальная функция Update уже используется в VCL контролах, поэтому для полной совместимости заменил на UpdateData()